# Grouping column events to create start and end dates of events

Tags: r

i'm new to programming and R.  i'm a bit stuck. i have the following data table.

```
Date        |ONIstatus  
01/10/1993  |Average  
01/11/1993  |Average  
01/12/1993  |Average    
01/01/1994  |Average    
01/02/1994  |High    
01/03/1994  |High  
01/04/1994  |High  
01/05/1994  |High  
01/06/1994  |Low  
01/07/1994  |Low 
01/08/1994  |Average  
01/09/1994  |Average  
01/10/1994  |Average    
01/11/1994  |Average    
01/12/1994  |High    
01/01/1995  |High  
01/02/1995  |Low  
01/03/1995  |Low  
01/04/1995  |Low  
01/05/1995  |Low
```

I want to extract start and end dates based on sequences of events in the 'ONIstatus' column. So, start date would be at the first set of 'ONIstatus entries' and end date would be when the next sequence starts - So, for example the first few sets of results desired output would be

```
Start Date  | End Date   | ONIstatus  
01/10/1993  | 01/02/1994 | Average  
01/02/1994  | 01/06/1994 | High
01/06/1994  | 01/08/1994 | Low  
01/08/1994  | 01/12/1994 | Average
01/12/1994  | 01/02/1995 | High
```

and so on... I want to loop over the entire data set which has several 100 entries.

I've been trying to do this with Dplyr and rle, but not having much luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
s <- rle(as.character(df$ONIstatus))
df_final <- data.frame(ONIstatus = s$values, length = s$lengths)

#end index
df_final$end <- cumsum(df_final$length)
df_final$desired_end <- df_final$end +1
#start index
df_final$start <- df_final$end - df_final$length + 1

#start_date & end_date calculation based on start & end index
df_final$start_date <- df$Date[df_final$start]
df_final$end_date <- df$Date[df_final$desired_end]

#final output
df_final <- na.omit(df_final[,c('ONIstatus','start_date','end_date')])
df_final
```

Output is:

```
  ONIstatus start_date   end_date
1   Average 01/10/1993 01/02/1994
2      High 01/02/1994 01/06/1994
3       Low 01/06/1994 01/08/1994
4   Average 01/08/1994 01/12/1994
5      High 01/12/1994 01/02/1995
```

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(15L, 17L, 19L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L
), .Label = c("01/01/1994", "01/01/1995", "01/02/1994", "01/02/1995", 
"01/03/1994", "01/03/1995", "01/04/1994", "01/04/1995", "01/05/1994", 
"01/05/1995", "01/06/1994", "01/07/1994", "01/08/1994", "01/09/1994", 
"01/10/1993", "01/10/1994", "01/11/1993", "01/11/1994", "01/12/1993", 
"01/12/1994"), class = "factor"), ONIstatus = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Average", "High", "Low"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", 
"ONIstatus"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%
    group_by(ONIstatus) %>% 
    summarise(StartDate = min(Date), EndDate = max(Date)) %>%         
    mutate(EndDate = lead(StartDate)) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    mutate_at(2:3, funs(format(., "%d/%m/%Y"))) %>%        
    select(StartDate, EndDate, ONIstatus)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   StartDate    EndDate ONIstatus
#       <chr>      <chr>     <chr>
#1 01/10/1993 01/02/1994   Average
#2 01/02/1994 01/06/1994      High
```

Comment: can't we just load `dplyr` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually that didn't work, i'm actually trying to do this with a very long dataset, 1000s of entries -  this only matches my example results!

Comment: @MatthewJWatts No problem.  As I was using your example, I don't know whether I am missing something on your original data

Comment: Hi akrun, no that is the general layout of the data set (first data table) although the real data set has several hundred entries. For some reason your code just returns the first two 'events' from the table. cheers

Comment: @MatthewJWatts  I am grouping by the ONI_Status and getting the min and max date.  So, it is not clear why you get only two events

Comment: so basically, in your results the desired function would have also picked up  01/06/1994  |Low  
01/07/1994  |Low                 and categorised this as low with the start & end dates. I've updated my initial post so it makes more sense i.e. what i want to achieve. thanks for your help!!!!!